# Magento Puts -1 in My URLs Can I Remove Programatically?

Tags: magento

I have to create a number of new stores inside my Magento installation. One thing that this does is forces me to have to do a LOT of reindexing on the entire site. For most of these this is not an issue at all, however I have seemed to always have issues with my URL index.

For some reason when I reindex my URLs it wants to put "-1" at the end of all my URLs. From what I understand this is for some sort of duplication that is in the system somewhere. I would really like to get rid of these so they no longer have the -1 inside of them. My reindex is still running so I am hoping that this will end up working itself out once it completes (right now I am thinking it is going to take a few days on our dev server). However if they do not remove themselves I may need to find an alternate solution.

If I were to write a script of a query that were to simply remove these redirects from the system do you think this will break the entire system? Has anyone done anything like this before?

My biggest concern is that if truncate the entire table and start from scratch, my products will not be visible on the website until it rebuilds and right now that process appears to take about 3 days.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that all the URLs with the -1 inside of them have value RP in the options column. What does that mean?

Comment: There is more on this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614738/magento-removing-numbers-in-url-key-product-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I've found to get around this is make sure you you have no pending indexing processes, if so take care of them BEFORE this as well as making a database backup:

Admin -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Manager.

Request Path search for "-1.html" (minus double quotes)

Remove all of them and re-index "Catalog URL Rewrites" Under System -> Index Management.

I believe the duplicates come about from stale or improper indexing when creating a new product its inserted, then during indexing a duplicate is created.

Hope this helps.