# Catalog URL Rewrites index stuck

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

My catalog URL Rewrites in Magento are stuck on processing. When I run the shell/indexer.php script I get the following error

> Catalog URL Rewrites index process unknown error: exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'sugar-tablets.html-1' for key 2' in
>   /home/healthra/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/healthra/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->
>   execute(Array) #1
>   /home/healthra/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_
>   Pdo->_execute(Array) #2
>   /home/healthra/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>   Zend_Db_Sta
>   tement->execute(Array) #3
>   /home/healthra/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db
>   _Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `mg_core...', Array) \#4
>   /home/healthra/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337):
>   Zend_Db_
>
>   Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE`mg_core...', Array) #5
>   /home/healthra/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632):
>   Varien_Db_A
>   dapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `mg_core...', Array) #6
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysq
>   l4/Url.php(257):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('mg_core_url_rew...', Array, '
>   url_rewrite_id=...') #7
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(363):
>   Mag
>   e_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Url->saveRewrite(Array,
>   Object(Varien_Object
>   )) #8
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(559):
>   Mag
>   e_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshProductRewrite(Object(Varien_Object),
>   Object(Varien
>   _Object)) #9
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(253):
>   Mag
>   e_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshProductRewrites('1') #10
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(246):
>   Ma
>   ge_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('1') #11
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(
>   249): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites() #12
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll() #13
>   /home/healthra/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll() #14
>   /home/healthra/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Process-
>   reindexEverything() 
>   #15
>   /home/healthra/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198):
>   Mage_Shell_Compiler->run(
>   ) #16 {main}

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this problem?

Comment: Is this on a multiple store installation? Despite the fact that Magento doesn't allow it, do you have two product entries sharing the URLkey "sugar-tablets"? Magento usually assigns the dupe entry a -1 on save (-2 for the next iteration) as URLkeys for product must be unique.

Comment: hi yes its a multiple store installation. How would I remove or check the url key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019584/magento-puts-1-in-my-urls-can-i-remove-programatically/5023457#5023457

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315684/magento-catalog-url-rewrites-stuck-on-processing

Answer (score 4):

Have a look here: [Magento Puts -1 in My URLs Can I Remove Programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019584/magento-puts-1-in-my-urls-can-i-remove-programatically/5023457#5023457) and also here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9342/.

I found that removing all lock files in `/path/to/mage/var/locks/index_process*.lock`, truncating `core_url_rewrite` and then reindexing cleared the issue.