# Magento adding thousands of rewrites

Tags: magento

We're having problems with our rewrites in Magento. Per day thousands of new product rewrites are being generated. At the moment we have 236940 product rewrites in our store and no solution yet.

It seems there is a loop in the rewrite process. The problem seems much like the one in this post: [Magento - Removing numbers in url key/product url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614738/magento-removing-numbers-in-url-key-product-url)

The problems has something to do with having identical product url's.

This issue generates two problems:
1. the products will have a different URL daily in Google
2. the magento installation is filling with rewrites, which most certainly will cause trouble

What should we try to fix the product rewrite loop?

Answer (score 1):

You will lose all of your stored rewrites by doing this, but you could truncate the `core_url_rewrite` table and re-index.  That would give you a fresh start.