# Magento appending '-1' in Category URL Key in frontend

Tags: magento

Magento is appending '-1' only to certain categories URL key despite not being defined by us like that in backend.

Eg. if URL key for category 'sample' is 'sample' .. in frontend its showing as '/sample-1'

It's not the case with all categories but 2 or 3 that too in desktop version alone. It's working fine in mobile version. What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you check the answer by Alan Storm here at `http://stackoverflow.com/a/13616639/1749007`

Comment: hey thanks! does it work for category urlkey as well?

Comment: And the problem is with 2 or 3 categories only. others re working fine.

Comment: but the issue is with only particular categories. what could be the root cause? Do u have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that can cause this.

Duplicate Categories trying to use the same URL,  upon reindex Magento will auto increment these values. To the next higher integer.

It's sometimes easy to miss.

Say you have the category "shoes" as a subcategory of "women"

The URL key created automatically for this category would be "/shoes"

Now say you have the category "shoes" as a subcategory of "men"

This category would automatically have the url key of "shoes" however because it already exists Magento will auto increment this key to "shoes-1"

Under a multi-store instance of Magento,  you also can't have two categories with the same url keys even if they are part of different stores.

Additionally, Magento Enterprise 1.13 has a whole different problem with auto increments of URL Ids

What version of Magento are you running and is it a multi-store platform?  I can provide further assistance from there.

Comment: My EE version is 1.5.1.0. But as far to my knowledge there is no duplication. The category is for Best Selling Commodities.